# requirements.txt with packages in pypi and fury

Tags: python, pip, gem-fury

As I'm using elastic beanstalk, i have to specify a requirements.txt files with all my packages. The issue I have is that one of the package must be fetch from gemfury, and i'm not sure how to do so.
The requirements.txt file generated from pipenv lock -r looks like this:

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
--extra-index-url https://repo.fury.io/123456/fdp/
click==6.7
flask==1.0.2
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.14.4
py-fdp-utils==1.1.6
pycodestyle==2.4.0
```

py-fdp-utils is my private package that i want to get from gem fury.

If i run, it will fail on the first package with the following error:

> pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://repo.fury.io/123456/fdp/click/

How can i specify requirements.txt to use gem fury index only for this package ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Gemfury docs you might try something like this:

```
--index-url https://pypi.fury.io/USERNAME/
--extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/
private-package=0.0.1
```